# EF Code First Migration - Property migration

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first, migration

So Imagine this situation:

```
namespace SC.BL.Domain
{
  public class User
  {
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public String Adress { get; set; }
    public int PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public char Gender { get; set; }
  }
}
```

EF Code first migration is enabled. I implemented code-based migration by using 'enable-migrations'

My **DbInitializer** is set to use the **MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion** initializer

Now my question is, I would like to migrate one property into multiple properties, without the loss of data, after this the old property may be removed!

Suppose I have in my database the following,

> Name: User1
>
> Address: Emmalaan 2, Gelderland
>
> PhoneNumber: 0471250950
>
> Gender: M

Now I want to change my User class to the following:

```
namespace SC.BL.Domain
    {
      public class User
      {
        public String Name { get; set; }
        public String StreetName { get; set; }
        public int HouseNumber { get; set; }
        public String City { get; set; }
        public int PhoneNumber { get; set; }
        public char Gender { get; set; }
      }
    }
```

So now I want that after migrations, the data in the database is changed (without dataloss) and put in the right properties.
Where can I till the migrator to do something like this?

> Name: User1
>
> StreetName: Emmalaan 2
>
> HouseNumber: 2
>
> City: Gelderland
>
> PhoneNumber: 0471250950
>
> Gender: M

**Is this possible via migration? And how is this done?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the only thing you could do is the editing of the generated migration to do the transformation you want.

Inside *Up()* method of the migration:

1. use the *Sql()* method to write the data into a temporary table
2. migrate the table to the new structure (with the generated code)
3. use the *Sql()* method to take all the data (splitted as you want) from the temporary table so you can fill the edited table

in the *Down()* method the inverse of *Up()*.

Comment: **Thank you**, I'm going to give this a try soon!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that this is possible via migration. You want to change structure of table, and you want that migration automatically separate data in different columns. I think that this is not possible. I think that better way is to only add columns by migration and after that you can create SQL procedure for splitting and updating data to different columns.

Comment: I thought maybe I could code something in the Up() method in the Configuration class that splits the properties